# Batik/Rhino JavaScript support?

Tags: svg, rhino, batik

Just want to get a sanity check on this before wasting too much time - does Batik actually have usable JavaScript support in its SVG display and rasteriser?

Problem: I've got code which generates SVG files, using a few thousand lines of fairly complex JavaScript. This works on Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, and IE9. I've spent the morning trying to get Batik to display a sample SVG file (in Squiggle) and to rasterise it to png/pdf/etc. I've already fixed one problem (I had to move a text node into the DOM to get `splitText` to work), and the next problem is only a few lines down (`nodeValue.trim()` doesn't work on a text node).

Just about to give up and ignore Batik (v1.7, downloaded yesterday), unless someone has some positive experience of it?